# SharePoint 2013 - Redundancy for Central Administration

Tags: 2013

Please let me know if I'm not understanding SharePoint completely, but if in a server, there is only one application server (the server that hosts CA).... and this app-server goes down, CA is inaccessible (along with other services).

If redundancy is wanted on the application server tier - or more specifically, to have Central Administration always available - would you just join server to the farm and.....?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run Central Administration on more than one server.  Spence Harbar has a great blog post about the details: http://www.harbar.net/articles/spca.aspx

Comment: I noticed the post is dated before the release of SharePoint 2013.... Is the information still accurate to the latest edition?

Comment: Yes, the architecture is the same for 2010 and 2013 as far as Central Admin is concerned.

Comment: If you could verify the following as correct (so I know.... that I conceptually understand it): Pop the SharePoint installation disk into web server(s) and run through until I see the [Advanced] button. Set it so it can host the web application. Using AAM, change it so it doesn't redirect to original server. This works because even if the original server goes down, the web front ends can pull CA information from the CA configuration database on the database servers.

Comment: yes you understand correctly.